# Is there a good website to plan a trip via trains in Europe?

Tags: europe, online-resources, planning, guides, trains

My wife and I have decided to move across Europe by train.
Do you know of any good sites for planning a trip via train (schedule and maybe prices)?
We're going to go across Europe from east (Russia and Baltic countries) to west (France and Germany).
I've found only one so far: [OEBB](http://www.oebb.at/).

Comment: You might want to checkout http://www.rome2rio.com Not a map, but certainly a good tool to evaluate routes

Comment: None of the five or more sites I've tried (including Rome2Rio) can find a train route from Spain to Romania.  Maps show routes.  Milan is on the way, but the first site that was able to handle Milan to Bucharest insisted that part of the trip is by bus.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Seat 61 is the absolute definitive guide for international rail travel. It has all the information you need about routes, prices, and schedule. It also has plenty of links to the places where you can price up and buy tickets, and where to buy them if you can't buy them online.

http://seat61.com/

If you have more specific questions you can ask them here obviously.

Comment: +1. I've not long got back from a train journey from London to Istanbul planned with information from this site. It is an excellent guide.

Comment: Seat 61 is the definitive *introductory* guide for train travel. But once you've reached the right country you'll need to turn somewhere else. The [DB (German railways) site](http://www.bahn.de/) is the reference site for timetables and routes in most of Europe.

Answer (score 36):

For route planning, the German Railway's website - http://www.bahn.de - is unbeatable for working out how to get from Helsinki to Madrid by train. It doesn't cover the ticket purchasing for journeys outside Germany though.

Comment: And for trainspotters, check out [railway maps in Europe and elsewhere](http://www.bueker.net/trainspotting/index.php).

Comment: It's also incomplete for Spain. It includes the big trains, but the small trains are often missing. Inside Spain, you'll want to use http://www.renfe.es/

Answer (score 20):

I'm surprised no answer so far has mentioned [Raildude](http://www.raildude.com/). This is a very useful, community-driven website for international trains in Europe. It is particularly focussed on budget travel, and indeed originates from a Interrail-related website.

### Hafas is not always accurate

I'd like to issue a word of warning about Hafas-based search engines. [Bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de), [B-Rail](http://hafas.bene-system.com/bin/query.exe/nn?L=b-rail), [ÖBB](http://www.oebb.at), and [NS Hispeed](http://www.nshispeed.nl/nl/internationale-treinplanner) are all based on the same international train database known as Hafas. It relies on participating train companies submitting their timetables, and is not always complete. In my experience:

- **It is not complete**. It's all-to-easy to think it is complete because it has so many trains, but it is not. In my experience, the further from Germany, the more trains are missing. I've taken decent trains in Spain that were not registered in Hafas.
- **It contains invalid connections**. For example, in Sweden, each railway station has a *minimum transfer time*. HAFAS is not aware, so it might recommend a connection with a 10 minute change whereas the minimum transfer time is 15 minutes. Minimum transfer time in this case means that connections are guaranteed, so that tickets are replaced if a connection is missed. With a connection less than the minimum connection time, this guarantee will not work.
- **It is even less complete around timetable shifts**. Each year in the beginning of December, timetables change. Around the shift of timetables, *Hafas* is *very* incomplete, even in Germany. In practice, planning a Christmas holiday is not possible with a *Hafas*-based search engine, because so many trains are missing or only registered extremely late.

The different *Hafas*-based search engines have slightly different features. For example, [B-Rail](http://hafas.bene-system.com/bin/query.exe/nn?L=b-rail) permits to specify the maximum number of connections, whereas [Bahn.de](http://www.bahn.de) allows to specify the minimum change time. Most allow to have one or more *via* stations. By combining those features, one can often get a much better connection than to simply write *Stockholm* to *Madrid* in an arbitrary search engine.  For example, you may want to avoid changing trains in the middle of the night, or increase the transfer time after a train that is often late.

### Complementary sources

- If possible, use the various national railway websites to double-check the timetable obtained with *Hafas*. For example, inside Spain, [Renfe](http://www.renfe.com/viajeros/index.html) have a much more complete and reliable timetable than any international website (although they cannot list connections with more than one transfer). Most, if not all, countries have national railway company websites. [This list on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_railway_companies#Europe) might get you started.
- The German forum *Drehscheibe Online* has a [list of PDF timetables](http://www.drehscheibe-foren.de/foren/read.php?30,4575048) for the various national railway companies, where available. Personally, I love to browse paper railway timetables. However, for most countries it can be quite hard to find the correct timetable.
- For long-distance trains, browse earlier-mentioned websites such as Seat 61 and Raildude. The latter specifically mentions connections between major cities, whereas the former is mostly written from a UK perspective.

Comment: Regarding the connection times. At bahn.de website you can customise this parameter. You can choose the minimum you want. If you miss a connection it's your problem, and you won't automatically get a refund. In Germany, with the cheapest tickets you have to take specified trains. If you miss one of them, you can take another train, but you probably have to pay an extra fee. If you buy these tickets ("Sparpreis" & co.) you are alone responsible to get your connections.

Comment: @MarcelC you can only specify one global minimum connection time. The problem is that a station like Stockholm C requires 20 minutes, but Boden C requires only 5 minutes. There are 15 minutes between the day train Narvik–Luleå and the night train Luleå–Göteborg, and this connection is guaranteed, but not shown if one specifies a minimum 20 minute connection. I've lost connections in Sweden several times while traveling Sweden–Spain, and they've always replaced my tickets immediately — of course when my change time was sufficient.

Comment: It depends on the fine-print. For some kinds of tickets you get a refund for other you don't. The cheaper the ticket, the less you can ask for ...

Comment: Inside Europe the CIV rules apply for any international ticket. You can read about them [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIV_%28rail_travel%29) and [here](http://www.cit-rail.org/en/rail-transport-law/cotif/). Among other things, in all but exceptional circumstances, the railway company is required to transport you from beginning to the end *if your travel is on one ticket*. This means replacing missed connections or refunding tickets that have become unuseable due to delays, regardless of the ticket flexibility.

Comment: The relevant article is article 32: *§ 1 The carrier shall be liable to the
passenger for loss or damage
resulting from the fact that, by reason
of cancellation, the late running of a
train or a missed connection, his
journey cannot be continued the same
day, or that a continuation of the
journey the same day could not
reasonably be required because of
given circumstances. The damages
shall comprise the reasonable costs of
accommodation as well as the
reasonable costs occasioned by
having to notify persons expecting the
passenger.*

Comment: There are some other relevant articles. But this applies to the full COTIF signatories, meaning Europe and the former Soviet Union.

Comment: In addition, inside the EU there is the [Passenger Rights and Regulations](http://www.bahn.com/i/view/GBR/en/services/passenger_rights/passengers-rights-international-services.shtml) since 2009. *Where it is reasonably to be expected that the delay in the arrival
at the final destination under the transport contract will be more
than 60 minutes, the passenger shall immediately have the choice
between:

Comment: (a) reimbursement of the full cost of the ticket, under the con-
ditions by which it was paid, for the part or parts of his or
her journey not made and for the part or parts already made
if the journey is no longer serving any purpose in relation to
the passenger’s original travel plan, together with, when rel-
evant, a return service to the first point of departure at the
earliest opportunity. The payment of the reimbursement
shall be made under the same conditions as the payment for
compensation referred to in Article 17; or

Comment: (b) continuation or re-routing, under comparable transport con-
ditions, to the final destination at the earliest opportunity; or
(c) continuation or re-routing, under comparable transport con-
ditions, to the final destination at a later date at the passen-
ger’s convenience. So, in summary, inside the EU, in case of serious delay, **you always are entitled to a refund**, except in case of war or nuclear disaster (those are explicitly named in COTIF...)

Comment: I am aware of this rules. Bt that's for "serious" delays. However, If you are traveling in german on a saver fare, with an obligation to use a given train and you miss it because of a small delay, you can use whatever train you want on the same road but have to pay an extra fee if no more saver fares are available on that road.

Comment: Other resources are useful as are your remarks but your alternatives really aren't alternatives at all. Renfe might have more complete timetables *inside Spain* but does it cover the rest of Europe better than HAFAS? An alternative to HAFAS would be a website/database with better coverage all over Europe, not national train companies websites, paper timetable or guides focused on specific journeys.

Comment: @Annoyed I have replaced "Alternatives" by "Complimentary sources".  Does this satisfy you?

Comment: Yes, perfect, sorry for the downvote.

Comment: @AndréPeseur My reply is a bit late but if you miss a connection with a German saver fare even by a minute you are entitled to use another train without paying extra to your destination. That was also true in 2012. The above quoted rule is not only for "serious delays" (whatever the definition of that is) but for any delay (with some caveats for expected delays below 60 minutes at the final destination).

Answer (score 13):

I suggest to use [InterRail pass](http://www.interrailnet.com/) instead of buying tickets. This is cheaper if you plan to travel more than few thousand kilometers.

For schedules, search HAFAS on Google. This is the common database shared by most rail companies in Europe (e.g.: [Germany](http://www.reiseauskunft.bahn.de/), [Switzerland](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch), [Belgium](http://plannerint.b-rail.be/))

Finally, for dreaming, check [Orient-Express](http://www.orient-express.com/).

Comment: Buying passes from North America is a HUGE savings over buying individual tickets once in Europe. My 8 day pass for train travel in England (bought from Canada) cost less than one of the one way legs I knew I wanted to do would have cost had I bought that ticket in England. Run the numbers well in advance because you need to leave time for the paper passes to be shipped to North America before you leave.

Comment: InterRail passes are great if you have a planned itinerary. If you like to wander randomly wide and far the passes cover certain areas so if you have a pass that covers the south and you have a sudden whim to head north or east it might not be flexible enough. At least that's what I found ten years ago on my first europtrip.

Comment: You can buy an InterRail pass that is valid for all countries. But flexibility is more expensive.

Comment: Just note that Interrail and Eurail passes are not valid in the baltic countries, in Russsia, Ukraine and Belarus.

Comment: Rail passes can be a good deal but in many cases they are not cheaper, and as time goes on that gets worse. Cheap early bought tickets are the cheaper option in most cases. And remember InterRail for Europeans, Eurail for the rest of the world, both have many different versions on top of that.

Comment: @KateGregory Buying tickets on the day of travel is the most expensive possible way.  But, rather than buying a pass, you could also buy advance tickets (from home, in advance) and collect them from a station in Europe. For instance: London-Edinburgh, first class, return, bought immediately before travel: £426. Bought in advance on a website: £106.70.

Comment: @RichardGadsden I know. A three day pass covering England and Scotland might be less than 200 pounds. It compares well to advance tickets and insanely well to last minute tickets

Answer (score 11):

[**EURail**](http://www.eurail.com/home) should be a good place to plan the trip.

They do go as far east as Poland and Bulgaria, but no further than that.

[**EuroStar**](http://www.eurostar.com/) is another network that may be useful, but it stops short of EURail on the eastern side.

Comment: What do you mean by "stops short of Eurail?". It connects the UK to France/Belgium, and both of the latter are countries where you can use your Eurail pass.

Comment: I mean that EURail goes further east than EuroStar does.

Answer (score 11):

The site that stands out by a mile is [seat61.com](http://www.seat61.com/). Really well written, very comprehensive, and has all the information you'll need on how to book when you've decided. I use it all the time!

Answer (score 10):

If you travel through the Baltic countries, prefer the bus to the train. Buses are faster, more frequent and more comfortable than trains. Once you are in Poland, you can switch to trains. So here are the sites:

- [DB TravelService](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/) has schedules that will cover the whole trip, apart from the buses in the Baltic countries. It only has fares for trains within Germany. And for some trains to and from Germany.
- [Go Rail](http://www.gorail.ee/) for the trains from Moscow or Saint Petersburg to Tallinn.
- [Lux Express](http://www.luxexpress.eu/) is operating buses between the Baltic countries, but also between Tallinn and Saint Petersburg and Vilnius and Warsaw.
- For train travel within Poland, use the [PKP route planner](http://rozklad-pkp.pl/bin/query.exe/en?).
- For train travel to and within Germany, use [DB TravelService](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/).
- For train travel to France, use [DB TravelService](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/) or [Voyages SNCF](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/).
- For train travel in France, use [Voyages SNCF](http://www.voyages-sncf.com/) and possibly [TER SNCF](http://www.ter-sncf.com/) for local trains.
- If you travel through Belgium, [SNCB Europe](http://www.b-europe.com/Travel) can be helpful for the long distance trains and [SNCB/NMBS](http://www.belgianrail.be/en/Default.aspx) for the local trains.

Answer (score 9):

Here is the [Interrail map](https://www.interrail.eu/en/plan-your-trip/interrail-railway-map):

On the site, it is also available as a [14Mb PDF](https://www.interrail.eu/content/dam/pdfs/interrail/resources/Interrail_2019-LR-def4.pdf) that you can zoom for details.

As speed/duration depends on many factors, the map only distinguishes between high speed lines, main lines and other lines.

[image: Interrail map]

Comment: Nice! This is the closest thing to what I want so far :)

Comment: An example for the duration: Frankfurt-Cologne takes between 1:03 and 2:24, both with ICE without to change trains

Comment: since it also depends on how often the trains come (for the connections across Europe), I think this answer is sufficient. And anyway, everything has flaws. Example: you are in italy and want to go to Slovenia. You will need to go to through Austria. I would recommend to take this map, and use http://bahn.de and try to plan your trip. There are very convenient ways, and others that are not.

Comment: I just found another helpful map: http://parisprague.files.wordpress.com/2009/10/train_europe.gif It shows only the times and only for some cities. It is still quite helpful about overall duration of a trip.

Comment: If you want a high-quality large scale printed map, get the Thomas Cook Europe Rail Map, available in all good bookshops.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by others Seat 61 is really the bible for European train travel and I would have been lost without it when planning and booking our train travel. It's focused on travelling from London but it's still really useful even if you're not starting your journey in London. It will point you in the right directions in terms of finding online timetables and tickets from the various operators and retailers.

I also stumbled across [Loco2](http://loco2.co.uk/) but haven't used it other than some quick searches. I'd be interested if there's anyone here that's used it and has some feedback.

Comment: In addition for UK travellers (at least) you can now book your entire journey from your home town/city train station right through to your destination http://www.wired.co.uk/news/archive/2013-11/12/loco2-european-rail-booking

Answer (score 6):

To go from Russia and Baltic Countries to Germany and France you have to go through the Poland. Although in other answers you have good international links, I think it's good to double-check connections on country-specific site. Polish railways has schedules and approximate prices on site: http://rozklad.pkp.pl/

Answer (score 5):

[This website](http://railteam.hafas.de/bin/query.exe/en?L=vs_railteam) is awesome to find route around europe by official.

btw, If you planned to travel in Europe by train, You should use an `Eurail` or `InterRail`(if you are EU/CH resident) It's more saving and can change itinerary any time without worries

Answer (score 1):

The best website to plan a trip in europe like an InterRail is http://www.eurorailplanner.com/

Comment: Is this your website? Are you in any way affiliated with it? Why is it `the best `?

Comment: Because you can plan a complex itinerary quickly. I used this website to plan my InterRail in November 2014. I think it's the best website because it's the only website I know that has multidestination schedules, that means all segments of your trip at the same time.