# How can I get to view the North Face of the Eiger in Switzerland?

Tags: transportation, switzerland

I can't seem to find information online about trains, buses, to take to get there etc. I would be travelling in from Stainach in Austria.

Is there a mountain station or similar that I can view it from?

e: I see from VMA's comment that I can go there via Grindelwald. What is the best way to get there from Stainach?

I'm thinking the train in the way of Stainach - Salzburg - Zurich - Bern - Grindelwald, but I can't get fares online for the Salzburg-Zurich-Bern portion. Anyone have an idea of the rough estimate of the fare?

Comment: http://maps.google.com/maps?q=46.5775,8.005278&ll=46.596855,8.030663&spn=0.069121,0.168571&t=h&z=13 I see here information about trains and even the buses. For example, from Grinderwald you can see the North Face, aren't you?

Comment: I'm not seeing anything about trains or buses on that link. And ideally I'd like to get closer than Grindelwald (not sure if that's possible though?)

Comment: Click on the 'Directions' link on the page VMAtm linked to, that'll show the transit options from your desired starting point.

Comment: moved information to the answer, with some screenshots

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [Google maps](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=46.5775,8.005278&ll=46.608177,8.014183&spn=0.034553,0.084286&t=h&z=14&iwloc=lyrftr:h,0x478f9eebbe0d7963:0x2808837e49a56570,46.600157,8.001823) and [sbb.ch](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/query.exe/en?seqnr=1&ident=c5.021677190.1309260550&HWAI=JS!ajax=yes!&HWAI=CONNECTION$C0-0!id=C0-0!HwaiConId=C0-0!HwaiDetailStatus=details!HwaiConnectionNumber=1!HwaiMoreDetailStatus=none!HwaiAdditionalInformation=none!;~CONNECTION$C0-0!HwaiMapStatus=UNDEFINED!HwaiMapNumber=UNDEFINED!HwaiMapSlider=UNDEFINED!;), the most closer railroad station is Alpiglen:
[image]. According sattelite map, you'll get beautiful view from there.

Not sure where are you getting from to the Eiger, so you can [search trains by youself](http://fahrplan.sbb.ch/bin/bhftafel.exe/en?seqnr=3&ident=c5.021677190.1309260550&input=8507375&boardType=arr&time=14:08).
If you have more specific information, please provide it.

---

Update:
[According oebb.at](http://fahrplan.oebb.at/), route and prices are (used local time just for example):

- 30.06.11 Stainach-Irdning 09:37 - Bischofshofen 10:48 - from [15.70 euro for 2d class](https://ticket.oebb.at/bin/frame_ticket.pl?ticket=ot_overview.pl?ld=5&xmlId=f4.06698166.1309332977:6:C5-0&LANG=EN) without VORTEILScard
- 30.06.11 Bischofshofen 11:08 - Mannheim Hbf 16:56 - from [106.80 euro for 2d class](https://ticket.oebb.at/bin/frame_ticket.pl?ticket=ot_overview.pl?ld=1&xmlId=iv.028371170.1309333517:8:C6-1&TicketperPost.x=1&LANG=EN) without VORTEAILScard
- 30.06.11 Mannheim Hbf 17:36 - Interlaken Ost 21:56 - unknown by oebb.at, unfortunately, but by http://bahn.de - from [95.60 euro for 2d class](http://reiseauskunft.bahn.de/bin/query.exe/en?revia=yes&existOptimizePrice=1&country=GBR&initialAvail=ON&dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D001_KIN0001_qf-bahn_LZ003&S=Mannheim%20Hbf&REQ0JourneyStopsSID=&REQ0JourneyStopsZ0A=1&Z=Interlaken%20Ost&REQ0JourneyStopsZID=A=1@O=Interlaken%20Ost@X=7868977@Y=46690691@U=80@L=008507492@B=1@p=1308593498@&trip-type=single&date=Th,%2030.06.11&time=16:51&timesel=depart&returnTimesel=depart&optimize=0&travelProfile=-1&adult-number=1&children-number=0&infant-number=0&tariffTravellerType.1=E&tariffTravellerReductionClass.1=0&tariffTravellerAge.1=&qf-trav-bday-1=&tariffClass=2&start=1&qf.bahn.button.suchen=)
- 01.07.11 Interlaken Ost 06:04 - Grindelwald 06:38 - unknown by oebb.at, unfortunately, but by http://sbb.ch - from [CHF 5.20 (near 4.4 euro) for 2d class](https://www.sbb.ch/ticketshop/b2c/fahrplan.do?sprache=en&WT.ac=Preis_Kauf_Fahrplan_B2C&DCSext.wt_origin=Fahrplan&von=Interlaken%20Ost&nach=Grindelwald&reiseDatum=01.07.11&reiseZeit=00:00&via=&verkehrsmittel=&HWAI=JS!ajax=yes!&xmlHandle=http://fweb1p_pds.sbb.ch/bin/query.exe/en?showXml=1&xmlId=oi.029515207.1309334331:1:C0-0)
- 01.07.11 Grindelwald 07:17 - Alpiglen 07:38 - unknown by oebb.at, unfortunately, and by http://sbb.ch there is a bug with no founded station, but I think it is not very expensive

Also you can see [this question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/16/plan-a-trip-via-trains-in-europe) to get some more sites to search prices and trains.

Comment: I accepted this answer, but it didn't solve my train price question. I know how to use the Austrian railways website - however it doesn't (or won't give) a price for Stainach - Grindelwald, or even Stainach - Bern.

Comment: Sorry, didn't saw that. I'll search the prices soon

Comment: @victoriah updated the answer

Answer (score 7):

You can also view the North face of the Eiger from the **inside**. The [Jungfraubahn](http://www.jungfrau.ch/en/company/rail-cableways/) takes you from Kleine Scheidegg to the Jungfraujoch via a stop in the Eigerwall complete with panoramic windows. Looks like you can connect with mainline services from Grindelwald or Lauterbrunnen.

See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jungfraubahn

Comment: sure, just go to grindelwald and go up the jung frau bahn.  don't forget to get the awesome fridge magnet!!

Answer (score 3):

Alpiglen station, mentioned in a previous answer, is actually *too close* to the Eiger to afford a proper view!  The actual best viewing spot is [Kleine Scheidegg](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Kleine_Scheidegg), the [next station on the same line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wengernalp_Railway).

[image]
(photo mine)

[Restaurant Eigernordwand](https://jungfrauregion.swiss/en/summer/eat-and-stay/gastronomy/restaurant-eigernordwand/), a few minutes walk from the station, has beautiful panoramic views if you'd like to enjoy the scenery that inspired the Toblerone bar with a drink of your choice in your hand.