# Motorcycle tour of Sweden and Norway

Tags: sweden, norway, motorcycles

A friend and I are in the early stage of planning a two week motorcycle tour of Sweden and Norway next summer.

Our main consideration is the availability and cost of renting two motorcycles for the trip, preferably with a pick-up / drop-off in Stockholm. A secondary consideration is the ability to take the bikes into Norway for approximately half the trip.

We're looking for advice on renting, or possibly alternatives to renting, from those with experience or good advice on renting / borrowing bikes in Scandinavia.

- Who to rent from?
- What are the conditions?
- What (if any) alternatives to renting are there?
- How much should it cost?
- Can we ride on Australian unrestricted motorcycle licenses?

Thanks.

Comment: Might be worth re-reading the [help].  More than one question in a post isn't a great format for Stackexchange and is likely to get closed.

Comment: Hey @Marky just a wild general thought. Have you been to sweden and the far north? for sure it's amazing, but you're aware, it's very very very flat and big! It's ironic that Sweden is one of the few places other than Aus where you can drive for 19,0000 km and see exactly the same thing :)  Have you considered biking around the alps man? http://www.ultimatedrives.net/top-10-roads/details.php?route_ID=30003  http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/35428/19233  it's particularly awesome for you bikers. Just google for thousands of companies, articles, blogs etc http://www.edelweissbike.com etc etc

Comment: Note you may be thinking of the FJORDS on the left of norway. They're like a zillion miles away and (to some extent) you can only see then from boats. Sweden is 19,0000 km of totally flat road in forest. In contrast, after God made motorbikes, on the next day he made the Alps for your benefit, then He made southern germany so you have BMW, Beer, bike-fanatics, etc, and then He made Europe as a convenient support system for the Alps. Food for thought! :)

Comment: Thanks Joe. We're travelling from Australia so we don't have the luxury of popping over to the Scandinavia whenever we want. This means we need to pack it in a bit. So far I've been quoted SEK 11,900 for the rental, plus SEK 1 per km, for an ST1100 with panniers. We're budgeting on around 4,000 kms for the total trip, so the total rental cost looks around SEK 15,900, or approximately $2,400 in our money, about the same as the cost of the flight to get there in the first place. Then of course fuel, food and accommodation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Renting in Scandinavia is quite expensive: I found quotes for 5000 SEK for a week for a touring MC (that's dirty cheap and not representative), plus extra for accessories (2000 SEK for complete set of helm, bags etc.), plus 1 SEK/km, plus cost of accommodation (500 SEK/person on average for a reasonable accommodation, in Norway even more expensive), plus cost of sustenance (400-500 SEK/day if going out to eat, 100 SEK/day or less if you'll be preparing food yourself).

For a two-week 2000 km trip, that makes ~30000 SEK ~(3300 EUR) minimum per person without the cost of fuel (14.5 SEK-15 SEK per liter of petrol approximately).

There might be minimum age restrictions (drivers under 24-26 are insured for higher premiums in Sweden, and might not be allowed to rent an MC). Concerning going to Norway -- shouldn't be a problem generally if you inform the renting agency. Might increase insurance premium though.

As to how to find them: "hyr motorcykel" in your favourite search engine should do the trick. Many sites won't have English versions, so be prepared for some translation. Renting agencies won't have problems speaking to you in English on the phone though. At this price level, I'd recommend contacting some directly, explain your plan and see if you can get a better deal from them.

Comment: Sometimes having a look at renting in Copenhagen, Denmark and just cross the bridge to Sweden - at least for car rentals that sometimes works out cheaper (but do compare!). http://www.aagesen.dk/rent_1.asp has been recommended for MC hire in Denmark - though I know nothing about MCs so have a look yourself.

Comment: It is completely nonsense, that you need at least 400 SEK/day for food not to starve. Being on a tight budget and not going out for food, it should be absolutely no problem to survive with 50 SEK/day or even less.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: Since OP will be travelling, they won't be cooking and preparing food themselves, presumably, which leaves only going out to eat -- and that's expensive. Fast food is around 60-80 SEK per meal, but realistically, do you really want to be eating McDonalds every day for two weeks? I live in Sweden and I can't survive (nor do I imagine it possible) for 50 SEK per day while hitting all the right food groups.

Comment: I don't understand why motorcyclists shouldn't be able to cook and prepare food themselves. Even without cooking, there's no need to go out for cold meals (bread, cheese, ham, marmalade) and it's no problem in Sweden to go out and have a proper warm meal well below 100 SEK.

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo: If they do cook, then yeah, it will be definitely cheaper than that, provided OP gets some local knowledge where and what to buy -- though Norway is more expensive than Sweden generally. I'll edit the answer to reflect our discussion.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I was only asking about the cost of renting the motorbikes, which will be the single biggest expense of this trip.