# Application to plan optimal route between multiple cities

Tags: online-resources, planning, road-trips, itineraries

I have looked at rome2rio and few other sites, but it did not fit what I was looking for. I want an application or site, where in, if I feed it a list of cities it should tell me which city should be my starting point and what cities I need to traverse (with specific order) and what should be my final destination. I am mainly looking for travelling by road. The whole purpose is I need to make sure that I do not travel back and forth and waste time, I should travel optimally.

Comment: In other words, you want to solve the [traveling salesman problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) (or at least the real-world practical version of the problem).

Comment: For travel by road, I think a map will be enough. Maybe something like ViaMichelin or Google maps, which will also include road connections and some other information like tolls and where you will find ferries.

Comment: Worth a look: http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/22071/32134

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem that you state is known in academia as the [Traveling Salesman Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Travelling_salesman_problem) as pointed out by @ZachLipton.

Googling for that expression in combination with app/website/software gives a few good finds.

As apps I could find e.g. [Concorde TSP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/concorde-tsp/id498366515?mt=8) and [Route4Me](http://appcrawlr.com/ios/route4me) (no affiliation nor experience).

A nice online tool is [Optimap](http://gebweb.net/optimap/) which seems to use Google directions. Here is a random route along the US east coast. You can choose between a roundtrip and or ending up in a different city than where you started from.

[image]

Comment: Yes, I had studied Travelling Salesman, Shortest path first and other networking problems during my computer science degree :) But I was curious if any of the websites provide a close solution. The above ones are sufficient for me for now.