App/website for planning a multiple-stop trip with public transportation
Can you recommend an app/website where I can enter a list of cities (e.g. Vienna, Prague, Cologne, Warsaw, Barcelona, Paris, Dusseldorf, Bratislava, Budapest, Brussels) and get as a result the best order and how to visit them by public transportation?
The area that should be covered is Europe. Depending on where train connections are available and how fast they are, sometimes covering 400 km air distance by train can be faster than 100 km with a slower connection, this means that tools for planning trips by car or bike relying on the road network aren't of much use.

See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/174375/how-can-i-see-what-the-fastest-driving-route-is-that-goes-through-n-places and https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/68363/application-to-plan-optimal-route-between-multiple-cities though I have no idea if any of the tools suggested support public transport (and some of them no longer work at all). The first question has an answer suggesting a manual method alternative.

Is price any consideration? The prices especially for high speed trains are all over the place and can be much more expensive than slower trains.

Price doesn't matter, top priority is a short travel time, second priority is to have as little changes as possible.

What constitutes 'best' is rather subjective.
Rome2Rio allows you to create a multi-stop itinerary by means of public transport.


But this tool requires you to research the best order yourself before? Exactly this is what I want to avoid.

Indeed. Rome2Rio doesn't give you the 'best' order. But, for a tool to do this for you, you first need to define what 'best' means.

For me, the fastest route is the best one. Additionally, I want to avoid switching trains/busses/planes. Price doesn't matter for me.

With 10 cities, the number of potential orders of visiting them is 3628800. That's one hell of an optimisation problem.
