# Can I use my Schengen visa to travel from Finland to Italy?

Tags: visas, schengen, indian-citizens, italy, finland

My single-entry Schengen visa was issued by Finland but I want go to Italy for a few days. Can I go by airplane.  Will the airport authorities will ask why I am going there and do I have to take with me any additional documents? Like hotel booking, retrurn ticket. After a few days, I will return back . Can I travel by airplane, rather then trains or buses?

Comment: You're supposed to get a visa from the main destination of your journey. If you enter the Schengen area in another country you can expect to be asked to either document that the issuing country is actually your main destination or (and it sounds like this is your case) explain why you applied for a visa in a different country from where you are going. If your explanation is not good enough your visa will be cancelled. The mode of transportation doesn't really matter.

Comment: With hotel booking documents can i carre

Comment: I doubt hotel bookings can explain why you applied for a visa in Finland and am going to Italy.

Comment: Is the plan to go first to Finland, then Italy for a few days before returning to Finland so you can fly back to India?

Comment: Your itinerary is unclear. If you want to go to Italy _in the middle of_ a visit to Finland, you will have no problems at all. Except if you fly on Ryanair or some other super-cheap carriers, you may not even have to show a passport except to check in for the flight. If you are talking about _replacing_ a trip to Finland with a trip to Italy, that will be very problematic.

Comment: My schengen visa issued from finland embassy. First I will enter finland then another day I will go to Italy with hotel booking and return ticket. Can i go by plan reater then train, buses, texi. What can I do?

Answer (score 3):

There are several variables and several questions here:

1. Have you told about your visit to Italy on a visa application form?
2. How much time are you going to spend in each country?
3. Will you get caught if you violate conditions of your visa?

Since this is a single entry visa, it should be issued by the country which is your main destination (unless main purpose is transit). If you intend to spend, say, 5 days in Finland and 1 day in Italy, and you have disclosed that on your application, you should be OK.

If, however, you got your single-entry Finish visa just for the sake of convenience (e.g. shorter line in front of the consulate), and intend to spend 1 day in Finland and 1 week in Italy, and failed to disclose your intention on a visa form then you are in violation of Schengen visa rules.

Will you get caught? It depends. Not likely, but

1. it is possible to encounter an inter-Schengen border control.
2. upon admission to Finland border guards may become aware that you are flying to Italy a day later (e.g. by doing a baggage search).

Answer (score 2):

Now that you have clarified your itinerary, you have gotten answers about the legality, so I'll just say a little about the other part of your question.

The mode of transportation doesn't matter, so yes you can go by plane. I would in fact recommend going by plane.

Last year we had a question about driving from Portugal to Finland by car ([What is the quickest way to get from Portugal to Finland by car?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/70742/what-is-the-quickest-way-to-get-from-portugal-to-finland-by-car)), a lot of the problems listed there will also apply if you substitute Italy for Portugal.

Comment: Means that if I have schengen visa then I can go with hotel booking and return ticket to Italy from finland.

Comment: @Hgfg yes.  But you won't need the hotel booking other than as a place to sleep (nor the return ticket except as a way to get back to Finland), because you will not pass through a passport control point when you fly from Finland to Italy and back.  Just be sure not to book an itinerary with a connection outside the Schengen area, such as in London, Dublin, or Belgrade.  If you do that, you will have to leave the Schengen zone, and you'll be unable to reenter it because your visa is only valid for a single entry.