# By train from Saarbrücken to Stockholm?

Tags: trains, germany, layovers, sweden

How long would it take to travel from Saarbrücken to Stockholm using the train?

I'm able to make 1 stop if necessary.

And what route do I need to travel?

Comment: Option 4 on this page: http://www.rome2rio.com/p/Saarbr%C3%BCcken/Stockholm 4 changes though, and takes 17 hours. Flying would definitely be quicker and could be cheaper, although less environmentally friendly.

Comment: @neo: Neither Hamburg nor Berlin have direct trains to Stockholm either. The farthest south you will find that is Copenhagen (which can itself be reached from Hamburg or Berlin).

Comment: @HenningMakholm You are right of course. For some reason I had Malmö in mind (for which there is a night train from Berlin). But for Stockholm you'd need another change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Apart from the regular travel search, DB also features a [*Sparpreisfinder*](https://ps.bahn.de/preissuche/preissuche/psc_start.post?country=DEU&lang=de&dbkanal_007=L01_S01_D001_KIN0001_qf-sparpreis_LZ003&psc-anfragedata-json=%7B%22showLayer%22%3Atrue%2C%22auslandsmodus%22%3Atrue%2C%22auslandPos%22%3A%22ziel%22%2C%22startBhfName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22zielBhfName%22%3A%22%22%2C%22tripType%22%3A%22return%22%2C%22datumHin%22%3A%22Mi%2C+22.06.16%22%2C%22sliderHinMin%22%3A%220%22%2C%22sliderHinMax%22%3A%221440%22%2C%22datumRueck%22%3A%22Do%2C+23.06.16%22%2C%22sliderRueckMin%22%3A%220%22%2C%22sliderRueckMax%22%3A%221440%22%2C%22schnelleVerbindungen%22%3Atrue%2C%22reiseprofilIndex%22%3A%22-1%22%2C%22schnellbuchung%22%3A%220%22%2C%22travellers%22%3A%5B%7B%22typ%22%3A%22E%22%2C%22bc%22%3A%220%22%7D%5D%2C%22klasse%22%3A%222%22%7D&qf-preissuche-departure-point=Von+Bahnhof+%28Inland%29+%85&REQ0JourneyStopsS1ID=&qf-preissuche-destination-point=%85+nach+Bahnhof+%28Inland%29&REQ0JourneyStopsZ1ID=&qf.preissuche.button.auslandsmodus=Start+oder+Ziel+au%DFerhalb+Deutschlands&ps-trip-type=return&date=Mi%2C+22.06.16&hsucheSliderHinfahrt_from=0&hsucheSliderHinfahrt_till=1440&returnDate=Do%2C+23.06.16&hsucheSliderRueckfahrt_from=0&hsucheSliderRueckfahrt_till=1440&ps.optimize=0&ps.travelProfile=-1&adult-number=1&children-number=0&infant-number=0&ps.tariffTravellerType.1=E&ps.tariffTravellerReductionClass.1=0&ps.tariffClass=2&scrambleCode=&captchaInputField=) (rough translation: *cheap price finder*). You will need to use the out-of-country one that I linked (hopefully the link doesn’t die), select Sweden as the country and Stockholm as the station. It features four options from Saarbrücken to Stockholm ranging from €139 to €169 if you don’t have a BahnCard (and are 31; I randomly put in an age because it asks you to and I didn’t want to risk youth prices).

If you can, you really should book a single through ticket. If you do, then it’s not your fault if you miss any train due to delays.

No matter how you do it, there is going to be a night connection somewhere. Since German railways do not see themselves as competent enough to offer night trains with sleeper cars, you are either restricted to a night in a sitting train or one at a station (one connection I can see has you wait 3:50 h in Neumünster — not exactly my definition of a successful night ;)). Of course, you can always break your journey into two, but you can’t book that *via* the *Sparpreisfinder* directly. However, if you set your eyes on a specific part in Denmark/Sweden, you can go back to the usual journey planner and select a stay of however long at a German station of your desire. You will still be able to book a through ticket.

The connections I got:

- 1. Regional train; leaves Saarbrücken at 15:47, arrives in Mannheim at 17:13 (RE 4114)
  2. ICE; leaves Mannheim at 18:00, arrives in Hamburg at 22:54 (ICE 572)
  3. InterCity (operated by DSB); leaves Hamburg at 23:42, arrives in Copenhagen at 06:56 (IC 231; this is a typical Danish intercity train set)
  4. X2000; leaves Copenhagen at 08:20, arrives in Stockholm at 13:39 (X2 530; [passport checks before you board in Copenhagen by the train staff and in Hyllie by Swedish border control](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/71793))
- 1. Regional train; leaves Saarbrücken at 16:46, arrives in Mannheim at 18:18 (RE 4116)
  2. ICE; leaves Mannheim at 18:29, arrives in Kassel-Wilhelmshöhe at 20:41 (ICE 274)
  3. ICE; leaves Kassel at 21:36, arrives in Hamburg at 00:36 (ICE 782)
  4. Regional train, leaves Hamburg at 00:45, arrives in Neumünster at 01:41 (RE 21140)
  5. A night at Neumünster station
  6. Regional train, leaves Neumünster at 05:30, arrives in Flensburg at 06:46 (RE 21050)
  7. InterCity, leaves Flensburg at 06:50, arrives in Fredericia at 08:10 (IC 5721)
  8. Lyntog, leaves Fredericia at 08:22, arrives in Copenhagen at 10:41 (LYN 51018)
  9. X2000, leaves Copenhagen at 11:20, arrives in Stockholm at 16:39 (X2 536)
- 1. Regional train; leaves Saarbrücken at 21:47, arrives in Mannheim at 23:35 (RE 4126)
  2. InterCity; leaves Mannheim at 02:15, arrives in Hamburg at 09:05 (IC 60478; I suspect that this is also a night train, but the *Sparpreisfinder* cannot find sleeping cars or whatever)
  3. ICE; leaves Hamburg at 09:28, arrives in Copenhagen at 14:22 (ICE 33; crosses the Fehmarn belt by ferry)
  4. X2000; leaves Copenhagen at 15:20, arrives in Stockholm at 20:39 (X2 544)

All this was plugging a random day.

You see that you get two general routes: Northwards to Hamburg and then either across the Danish mainland to Copenhagen or across the Fehmarn belt. The last leg is identical.