# Scandinavia and the rest of Europe in July

Tags: scandinavia

What are the options if one were to travel:

1) From Stockholm to Prague

2) From Stockholm to Amsterdam

Does Eurail cover these trips?

Comment: Welcome to TSE, please see [Tour](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour) and [How to ask a question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Much too broad. Scandinavia consists of 4 countries and Prague is in Eastern Europe. It is also possible to reach Denmark (continental Europe) from Sweden by car over the [Great Belt Fixed Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great_Belt_Fixed_Link).

Comment: If you're planning to use trains, see here: http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/16/19